# Touchpad faster in Y than X

Tags: touchpad, elantech

I have an Aspire S7 with Ubuntu 13.04 and most things work fine, but the touchpad is killing me.

The touchpad is (from 'xinput list')

⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]

The main problem I am having is that the tad is substantially more sensitive in the Y direction than it is in the X. Is there a way to correct this? Right now if I move my finger in a circle on the pad the cursor moves in an 0 shape.

There's also a lack of sensitivity that makes it hard to select small objects. I'm not sure if this can be helped or if it's a driver issue.

I've tried a few programs to tweak settings but I haven't been able to make it any better. Any help is great!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by adding

```
Option "VertResolution" "7"
Option "HorizResolution" "5"
```

to 50-synaptics.config (in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d)